# Positioning a div at specific fixed place irrespective of zoom and scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a header with fixed position and inside header I have navigation links but when I zoom into browser links are thrown out of window to right. How can I make the navigation links fixed to `50px` right no matter I zoom in or out.
[jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/7jLy2e7y/) I don't want to change properties of header.

```css
.header {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 500px;
  position: fixed;
  background: red;
  height: 60px;
}
.navlinks {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 50px;
  width: 30px;
  margin-top: 4px;
  height: 20px;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">hello
  <div class='navlinks'></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've already set the *fixed position* header to `width:100%` so the `min-width:500px` is unnecessary.

Remove that and the issue is solved.

```css
.header {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  background: red;
  height: 60px;
}
.navlinks {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 50px;
  width: 30px;
  margin-top: 4px;
  height: 20px;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">hello
  <div class='navlinks'></div>
</div>
```

[JSfiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/7jLy2e7y/)